# Scheme Symbols: Continuation Passing Style Examples

Tags: syntax, scheme, continuation-passing

In a [Wikipedia article about CPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) there is the following code snippet, ostensibly from Scheme:

```
(define (pyth& x y k)
 (*& x x (lambda (x2)
          (*& y y (lambda (y2)
                   (+& x2 y2 (lambda (x2py2)
                              (sqrt& x2py2 k))))))))
```

I cannot find any other examples, or an explanation for the usages of "pyth&", "*&", and "+&".  Much Googling has turned up only that there are other forms such as "=&" and "/&".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are just function names, `pyth&` is the CPS `pythagoras` procedure, `*&` is a CPS multiplication procedure and `+&` is a CPS addition procedure, different from their usual counterparts because they receive a continuation in the last parameter, the `&` at the end is simply a naming convention to remind you of this, which is stated at the beginning of the linked paragraph:

> In CPS, each procedure takes an extra argument representing what should be done with the result the function is calculating